# How to split domain-part from emailId in Android?

Tags: android

I am making validation in email id in which I want to make condition for domain-part after `.` not more than 255 character. for this I want to split domain-part after `.` like `user@gmail.commmm` in this I want to split after `.`. How can I do that?

**My validation code is**

```
/*validation for email*/
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {// validation for email Id
    boolean isValid = false;
    String expression = "^([_A-Za-z0-9-\\+])+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,255})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;

    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: This code does not show how you have tried to extract the domain part so far. Please go through the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its just java!

```
String email = "example@anymail.com";
String[] split = email.split(":");
split[0]; // this contain "example@anymail"
split[1]; // this contain "com"
```

Note:Your question is not clear!

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use following method to validate email.

```
public static boolean isValidEmailId(String email) {
        return Pattern.compile("^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$").matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

2. Or you can use string split operation to split string based on format and calculate length of string.